# WPF SQL execute script file ADO .net

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I need to execute a script based on a file.  Now before everyone links me to multitude answers of this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class ExcuteScript : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string sqlConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=ccwebgrity;Data Source=SURAJIT\SQLEXPRESS";

    string script = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Project Docs\MX462-PD\MX756_ModMappings1.sql");

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
    }
}
```

This seems to be old .net 2.0 code based on this error;

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information
```

Now I am very leery to go down the legacy code path, as it has bite me one too many times in the past.

Now I could parse out all the "GO" lines and execute each one at time but that seems kind of crazy.

What is the correct way to execute a .sql file in ADO .net 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is parsing out all the "GO" lines and executing each one at a time crazy? It would probably take you less time to do that than it took you to write your question.

1. Read the file into memory.
2. Split it into a set of independent statements.
3. Execute them in a loop.

Comment: It seems crazy not because of the work but seeing that there is one click in a query program